# Installing FreeTDS -Any new documentation more recent than 2011?

Tags: freetds

I have v1.00.94 latest version of freetds as of today, unzipped the file... now where exactly do these files go? I have used the newer sqlsrv drivers from Microsoft and to that end had to rewrite some queries, but now need to support the older: mssql_connect etc.. type queries.

The documentation on the site is very vague about which files exactly and how do you compile the source to dlls? Anyone with a clear noob type instructional on the procedure? I found something close here: https://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2011q2/026981.html but so outdated and doesnt appear accurate. I am running XAMPP (PHP v 7.0.2) on Windows 10.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the website hasn't been updated in some time, as you've noticed. I've [made pull requests that were accepted to the documentation](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/pull/71) that are in the repository on GitHub, but haven't been published to the website.

One option, and I realize it isn't ideal, is to clone the repository from GitHub's master branch and build the documentation yourself (or read it in RST format):

https://github.com/freetds/freetds

Good luck!